# Navigate between bootstrap dynamics tabs in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I have an angularjs application with bootstrap. In this one, I have a page with many tabs that I can dynamically add or remove.

When I have a lot of tabs they go on a second or third line. But I want something like the [dynamics tabs from angularjs material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs#dynamic-tabs). So I want to just have one line and navigate between all the tabs thanks to arrow button.

This is how I display my tabs:

```
<uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in listJobsViewCtrl.tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
      {{tab.content}}
</uib-tab>
```

This it what I have:
[image]
And what I want (not all styles):
[image]
Is it possible to do it with bootstrap ?

Comment: Short honest answer: `uib-tabs` doesn't support it naturally, it requires a new component either a third party lib or the implementation of a new bootstrap tabs component with pagination like `md-tabs` does. :/

Comment: Ok thanks. And do you know a third party lib which doing this?

Comment: I don't know any lib that does this apart from angularjs-material. You can try to replicate the current `uib-tabsed` logic and add your logic to it.